# Argument 2 may not be passed with the 'out' keyword

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I am new at programming, I am trying to insert values inside four arrays using one for loop. However I only get the error: (Argument 2 may not be passed with the 'out' keyword. I know that's something wrong around the console readline but I don't what I can do to turn around this situation. That's my code so far:

```
int size;
do
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("What is the size of the array: ");

} while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out size));

string[] name = new string [size];
double[] grade1 = new double [size];
double[] grade2 = new double[size];
double[] avarage = new double [size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    do
    {
        Console.Write($"Insert the name of student number: {i + 1}: ");
    } while (!Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine(), out name[i]));

    do
    {
        Console.Write($"Insert {i + 1}º grade: ");
    } while (!Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine(), out grade1[i]));
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString` doesn't return a `bool`, so you can't use `while (!Convert.ToString ...`. It also doesn't take a second argument like `out name[i])`. That is not valid anyway because an `out` parameter is always a single _variable_ and not a `string` that the array-indexer returns.

Comment: The code somehow confuses Convert.ToDouble() with Double.TryParse().  Confusing enough to the compiler to not produce a good "what the heck" error message.  Do use the latter.

Answer (score 2):

While [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `bool`, `Convert.ToString` and `Convert.ToDouble` do not, and unlike other languages, C# won't let you treat other types as `bool` to shorthand `null` comparisons. Thus, you generally can't use `!value` when `value` is not a `bool`.

Note that in the case of the second conversion, you're converting a string (console input) to a string, so it's *not* necessary - just take the string and check for [`IsNullOrWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) (although you'll need multiple line). Thus

```
do
{
    Console.Write($"Insert the name of student number: {i + 1}: ");
    name[i] = Console.ReadLine();
} while (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(name[i]));
```

For the third conversion, you could use [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) instead,

```
} while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grade1[i]));
```

Notably, most of the numerical types in .NET support `TryParse` methods, and converting a string to a string just to make code look the same is a good example of the YAGNI principle.